# dotnet build obj/project.assets.json' already exists

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core

When attempting to publish OR compile .NET Core application on Ubuntu I get the following error:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r ubuntu.16.04-x64 OR
dotnet build --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --configuration Release
```

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.401/NuGet.targets(123,5): error : The file '/media/sf_ubuntu_share/Marvin/SharedEntities/obj/project.assets.json' already exists. [/media/sf_ubuntu_share/Marvin/Marvin-Ubuntu/Marvin-Ubuntu.csproj]

I have removed the obj folder and all contents however this still hasn't resolved the issue. I am able to run these commands fine on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

This issue, I found out was, my compile had issues with the code sitting on a VM shared network drive. Once I moved the files onto a unix file system it worked fine.

Comment: I have the same issue, inside a Docker and the filesystem is mounted from  the parrent Linux system, but was only for 3 out of maybe 500-700 compiles, and I fully expect it to be gone or affect other compile on my next run.